# How can I wait for a callback before returning from eval()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, eval

I have a node.js script that reads in some JS code from a file, and passes it to an `eval()`. The code that passes the javascript to the eval is as follows:

```js
// read javascript code from file
var outputbuffer = '';
function output(data) {
  outputbuffer += data + '\n';
}
eval(javascriptCodeFromFile);
// do stuff with outputbuffer
```

The javascript code in the file is as follows:

```js
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('myfile.txt', function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    output('Error reading file');
  }
  else {
    output(data.toString());
  }
});
```

The problem is that the eval exits before the file read completes, as the file read is asyncronous. The eval simply starts the file read, and then exits, not waiting from the file read to complete. How can I make the eval wait for the callback before exiting? I have looked at promises and they seem PROMISing (pun intended) but I need someone to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: why don't you have that `js` code in a `.js/ts` file and simply import where you need ?

Comment: @Muhammad Usman the js code doesn’t come directly from a file, there are a few other things in the process. I just said that to make It simpler, as it’s not really important

Answer (score 2):

*Leaving all the downsides of eval, here is a direct answer to your question.*

---

Create a promise for keeping the event loop of the main thread busy.

Resolve the promise from within the script being eval. The script will have access to the `resolve and` reject` functions of the Promise since the evaluating script is within the scope of the promise.

```
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => eval(javascriptCodeFromFile));
p.then(()=> console.log(outputbuffer))
 .catch((e) => console.log('Rejected ::' + outputBuffer));
```

Here is a runnable example that demonstrates the main thread waiting for an asynchronous execution happens inside eval

```js
let jsCode = `
      setTimeout(() => (resolve('Hello from eval after two seconds')), 2000);
`;

console.log('waiting...');

let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      eval(jsCode);
})

p.then((data)=> console.log(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to have your eval'd code return a promise.

example:

```js
const code = `
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.readFile('myfile.txt', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        reject('Error reading file');
      }
      else {
        resolve(data.toString());
      }
    });
  });
`;

console.log('starting...');
eval(code)
  .then(str => console.log(str))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

It's also fine to make the Promise external to the `eval` and just call the `resolve` or `reject` from the eval'd code:

e.g.:

```js
const code = `
  var fs = require('fs');
  fs.readFile('myfile.txt', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
    else {
      resolve(data.toString());
    }
  });
`;

console.log('starting...');
new Promise((resolve, reject) => eval(code))
  .then(str => console.log(str))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Or the same thing with `await` and calling the async version of `readFile`

```js
const code = `
  require('fs').promises.readFile('myfile.txt')
`;

console.log('starting...');
main().then(() => console.log('...done'));

async function main() {
  try {
    let result = await eval(code);
    console.log(result);
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```